# Microsoft DNS server doesn't add new DHCP lease from Linux

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, dhcp-server

Server Setup: Microsoft DNS + Microsoft DHCP server

[image]

Client Setup: Linux live CD as DHCP client

Question: dhclient could get the IP assignment from Microsoft DHCP server, I could see the entry on the sever side, but somehow I can't get the DDNS update / add on Microsoft DNS server, what exactly goes wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your DNS zone is set to "secure update only" (it is the default) , then you need to set the credentials the DHCP server will use to update the DNS entry.

Otherwise the DHCP doesn't have permission to create the entry in DNS.

You need to have a (generally dedicated) AD user which is member of the `DnsUpdateProxy` group and configure the DHCP server to authenticate with this user against the DNS service.

You can set it in the DHCP server on the properties of the IPv4 node, in the "advanced" tab:

[image]

[image]

Comment: One step missing, I have to create a service account on AD and add it as member of dnsupdateproxy, then put it into "DNS dynamic update registration credentials" section.

Comment: @ThomasG.Lau thanks, updated.